# How to make blue hot metal

Tags: node-editor

I made this fire/hot metal node setup and can't figure out how to change it's natural colours to blue.  I tried colourizing the image texture (lava was used) but it didn't work.  Also tried using RGB to black and white with the image textures and playing around with hue/saturation, but nothing will change this natural hot metal colour.  I would post the node setup, but it was way to big to show in one picture.  However, I have posted the .blend.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **base colour** frame change **Blackbody** node to **RGB Input** or just disconnect **Blackbody** and set the colour in **MixRGB** socket, or set **Blackbody** to high value.

[image: final]

Comment: That worked!  Perfect solution